# I am using the select form in from bootstrap v4.5. but after i select an option the select option box becomes smaller

Tags: html, laravel, bootstrap-4

I am using the select form in from bootstrap v4.5. but after i select an option the select option box becomes smaller.

```
 <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">District*</label>
                    <select style="width: 100%" onchange="shipping_district({{($sum_total)- ($coupon_minus)}})" class="form-control" name="checkout_district_n" id="checkout_district">
                        <option>Dhaka</option>
                        <option>Chittagong</option>
                        <option>Barisal</option>
                        <option>Jessore</option>
                        <option>Rajshahi</option>
                        <option>Rangpur</option>
                        <option>Khulna</option>
                        <option>Sylhet</option>
                    </select>
                </div
```

[Modal before selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMoXm.png)
[Modal after selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vs0I.png)

Comment: i guess its working fine

Answer (score 0):

use the CDN and Jquery libraries:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.0-11/css/all.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.15.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ID `checkout_district` is affecting your SELECT field, you need to over write it. Thank you